# C++ Templates classes instancing twice

Tags: c++, dll

I've been working on a way to get a unique id for some of my classes, so the approach I'm currently working on is the following:

```
//id_object.h

class DR_UTIL_EXPORT IDBase
{
 public:
  static UInt32
  getNextID();
};

template<class T>
class IDClass
{
public:
  static const UInt32 ID;
};

template<class T>
const UInt32 IDClass<T>::ID = IDBase::getNextID();

//id_object.cpp

UInt32
IDBase::getNextID() {
  static UInt32 nextID = 0;
  return nextID++;
}
```

but the problem is that this doesn't work properly, for some reason there are classes that get instanced twice. These functions are used on 2 different projects (one is a dll and the other is an exe).

For example on Core.dll

```
IDClass<A>::ID == 0
```

but on *Application.exe*

```
IDClass<A>::ID == 8
```

A is a class defined on Core.dll

Comment: What should that two number the same as your ID number is dynamical ? [mcve]

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't understand your question

Comment: Where `getNextID` is defined? I mean don't you have a situation where it is defined several times in different binaries causing separate id sequences to be generated? Also this looks like you may be suffering from static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: id_object.h and id_object.cpp where getNextID is defined are part of another DLL (Utils.dll). So in this context i have App.exe which uses Core.dll and Utils.dll and Core.dll also uses Utils.dll